# batch cannot find path

Tags: windows, batch-file, dll, path

I am working on a game and what i simply need is for the game to write to a file on a specified path.

but every time I try I get error such as

> "cannot find path specified"

I have tried all combinations of `cd/` and path and `dir` and with bunny ears without bunny ears with "`\`" and so on but nothing  solves this error.

But as a requirement for this too is that I can not specify full path. because as this is a game. the path of the game will vary from pc to pc (maybe) wich means i want it to "search and find" the path matching what is in the code. so heres my code. any ideas?

```
   if exist cd "game\General_menus\users\%player%\programbase.dll" goto write
if not exist cd "game\General_menus\users\%player%\programbase.dll" goto addwrite


:write

echo %score%> cd "game\General_menus\users\%player%\playerdb.dll"

pause>nul

:addwrite

echo %score%>> cd "game\General_menus\users\%player%\playerdb.dll"
```

however the full path is: C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\game\game\General_menus\plugins

(but as I said. I want it to "detect rest of the path that's not specified)

edit==========================================================================0

currently working path= 
C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\game\Hacker_game\General_menus\plugins

i want the file playerdb.dll to be written to path:
C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\game\Hacker_game\General_menus\users\%player%\playerdb.dll

without having to manually lock it to C as path.  (like it will retrieve the path info  wich is why I use %CD%) then simply move 1 folder up. and then into users\player then write the file

and its still not working  :(

```
set path=%CD%

IF EXIST dir %path% /A:D(
    goto write
)else(
goto addwrite
)
cd users\%player%\playerdb.dll goto write
if not exist cd users\%player%\playerdb.dll goto addwrite


:write
echo %score%> "Hacker_game\General_menus\users\%player%\playerdb.dll"
pause>nul
:addwrite
echo %score%>> "Hacker_game\General_menus\users\%player%\playerdb.dll"
```

Comment: `if exist cd "game\General_menus\users\%player%\programbase.dll" goto write` That code is checking if the file `cd` exists.  I would assume you want to remove the `cd`

Comment: yeh i just added cd and cd/ "path" and i tried if exist "path" and i tried "if exist path" and i tried a lot more things too. but i find nothign that works. i tried to "set path" at begining of script. but nothing works :( and i also need the dection part however. it also says that when writing "if exist cd (path) that it cannot find the path that im actually trying to find. it didnt include the cd part in it. so for my point of view it seemed like that would work. but you might be right.

Comment: None of your code is valid syntax.  I suggest you start from the beginning and try again.

Comment: the entire code itself works perfectly. exept that part. i got it working in different part of the script thats similar. but for some reason it still dont work there ... and i really cant see the error thats why im here maybe u guys will be able to see the error and maybe tell me (so i can learn it)

Comment: If this is only part of a batch file how are we supposed to know that another part of it is not affecting this part. You can't tell me that you have replicated this code and it works in another part of your batch file: `echo %score%> cd "game\General_menus\users\%player%\playerdb.dll"`

Comment: this part of the code works perfectly:                                                    MKDIR  "game\General_menus\users\%usrname%"
echo %usrname%>> cd game\General_menus\users\%usrname%\programdata.dll
echo %passw%>> cd \General_menus\users\%usrname%\programbase.dll                           and this is pretty similar. i tried this solution in this area too. but yet it aint working

Answer (score 0):

The problem with batch is that it can be very.. nitpicky about certain things, paths for instance need to be full paths else you get the error. Maybe you could try putting the files for your game on your desktop in a folder?(though if your using visual studio to make this game you'll have to change were visual studio 'looks' for the files.

Though what you can do,is rather than trying to '>'/'>>' the var score to the specified path use the if statements to check that the file exists.

If it does then write the var to it, if not create the file then write to it.

here's the .bat I wrote to test it:

```
@ECHO OFF
::input your game folder path 
set path=C:\Users\Zachary\Desktop\testreceive.txt
::file to write to
set file=testreceive.txt
::var to write
set score=kappa

IF EXIST cd %path%(
    goto :output1
)else(
goto :output2
)


:output1
echo %score% > %file%
goto:EOF

:output2
break > "d:\testing\dblank.txt"
echo %score% > %file%
goto:EOF
```

Keep in mind the above isn't perfect,I'm still learning batch myself xD and it was a rush job so it has one bug(it'll open the file you are writing to), but hopefully it'll give you an idea of what to do.

EDIT:

I was in a hurry earlier but here is one potential way to side-step 'hard-coding' a path,that is changed after download.

```
@ECHO OFF
::file to write to
set file=testreceive.txt
::var to write
set score=kappa

::get things started
goto :reset

:reset
cls
echo Input the full path to [file-name]  
set /p path=
::hopefully put some error-checking here to see if the input matches the path

IF %path%==%pathcheck%(
     goto :logic
)else( 
    goto :reset
)

:output1
echo %score% > %file%
goto:EOF

:output2
break>"d:\testing\dblank.txt"
echo %score% > %file%
goto:EOF

:logic
IF EXIST cd %path%(
    goto :output1
)else(
goto :output2
)
```

This would fix any chance of the directory in the file being different from the actual directory

EDIT2:(hopefully the last one)

after mucking about a bit I found a bit of info on the dir command

```
@ECHO OFF
::input your game folder path 
set path=senpai
::file to write to



IF EXIST dir %path% /A:D(
    goto :output1
)else(
goto :output2
)


:output1
echo yay senpai noticed me!
pause
goto:EOF

:output2
echo boo senpai didnt notice me ;-;
pause
goto:EOF
```

more info on dir can be found here: http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html

the /A:D part specifies what your checking is a folder(atleast has I understand it the reverse would be /A:-D (not folder)

EDIT3:

Try changing:

```
echo %score%>
```

to:

```
echo %score% >
```

also check and see if the file knows what is in %player%.
use:

```
echo player:%player%
 pause
```

at the start of the file.
if that var is empty it would cause the error.
That's the last thing that comes to mind that would cause it to not work

Comment: well the problem is that i shouldnt really need the full path i think as long as everything its gonna search for is under same main directory. i have 1 main  directory called main, then i have sub folders such as game_missions, missions, tools etc etc.  lets say main script run from the main folder then i want it to etc call up  something from the tool folder and write to game_mission folder as just an example. im keeping it only operative within the sub folders that are in main fodler. so no matter where i move the main folder it will then still work as it will search for the this

Comment: and that is a must realy. to make sure it doesnt cause any bugs for future if the main folder gets moved for some reason. so that is my problem. i can see in your script that your solution will work. but then its depending on that the file is fixed to exact that location. and im 99 percent positive that what i try to achieve is possiblie. but for some reason i can not figure it out :(

Comment: C:\Program Files\Database\DBASE.EXE 

The root directory is the "C:\" part. 

"Program Files" is the next level. 

"Database" is a subdirectory under "Program Files"

 and "DBASE.EXE" is the actual file name.     I was in a hurry earlier but before I left I had thought of a way to fix that.. let me append it to the answer

Comment: still didnt get it to work :/  i updated the main post so u can see the full code with the changes and maybe a better explaination... i simply dont get it... this task should be so simple xDD but i simply cant figure it out -.-

Comment: nope still didnt work :( and yeh i did check the %player% (that was the firs tthing i did. i have echoed the path to see if it changes but still no results... damn why is it so buggy  -.-